# My crank slips I think

Tags: bmx

I've got a 2015 premium bmx. When I start to pedal, the left crank kinda slips, if that doesn't make sense, let me siimplify it. When I pedal, it's like it doesn't grab the chain or something, like it pedals and moves the chain but the wheel doesn't spin, only at first tho then it rides fine. But only when I try to pedal from the left side. I also have a freecoaster, maybe that's why but I don't know

Comment: Either the freewheel is slipping or your front cogs are worn (along with the chain) and it's "skipping".  (The freecoaster is likely more prone to the "freewheel slipping" problem, but the left/right side only problem is more likely associated with the worn cog ... and possibly a loose bottom bracket bearing.)

Comment: Look up the brand and model of the freecoaster and see if you can find a video for servicing it. If you're not up for that there's not much else to do than bring it to shop for reparation (if possible) or a new one or keep using this (you're sure it's not just the slack on a freecoaster which is noticably more than on a freewheel, right? also the 'left crank only' + 'only when start to pedal' might be just because you ride left foot forward?) Btw something like this can be quite informative: https://youtu.be/12I8iK12oqA.

Comment: Do you mean the left crank only? Not the right one? If so that sounds like you need to tighten your crank. Put plenty of grease on the square/spline before tightening.

Answer (score 1):

My son and I have had direct experience with this (he is helping me write this).  I realize this thread is very old, but I put this here in case others are finding it.

First, check the chain.  If it is worn too much (they elongate over time) it won't grab the teeth.

Second, Check the chainring,  Are the teeth sharp?  If so, you need to replace it?

Third, check the teeth on the rear cog.  Again, if the are sharp, you need to replace it.

Answer (score -2):

Your freewheel is failing - the pawls are not grabbing immediately which allows the chain to move without the rear wheel being powered.

This will not resolve itself over time, it will get worse.

Your two solutions are

Temporary) try washing the freewheel with solvent to get the gunk out.  Then let it dry and relube with light machine oil.

Longterm) Replace the freewheel mechanism with a new one.  You will probably need a new chain at this time too.

[image]

Comment: The question mentions freecoaster hub. They do not have freewheels.

Comment: @ojs feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: I know what a freecoaster is (the magic of internet search) but I have never used or serviced one so my answer would likely be incorrect too.

Comment: This does not answer the question as the author mentions that they have a freecoaster, which does not work at all like a cassette freewheel.

Comment: @Fatalize feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: @Criggie I don't want to answer, I'm just pointing out that your answer is not an answer to this question, therefore you should delete it.